# Is there any form to write to BigQuery specifying the name of destination tables dynamically?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Is there any form to write to BigQuery specifying the name of destination tables dynamically?

Now I have:

```
bigQueryRQ
.apply(BigQueryIO.Write
    .named("Write")
    .to("project_name:dataset_name.table_name")
    .withSchema(Table.create_auditedTableSchema())
    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

But I need the "table_name" as a dynamic table name that depends on the "tablerow" data that I want to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't provide an API to name the BigQuery table in a data-dependent way. Generally speaking, data-dependent BigQuery table destination(s) may be error prone.

That said, we are working on improving flexibility in this area. No estimates at this time, but we hope to get this soon.

Comment: Nope, not yet. This is tracked as [BEAM-437](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-437). You may want to "watch" that issue to get automatically notified of changes.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. 
How about to group rows by [tags](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/multi-input-output-transforms), and apply BigQueryIO.Write for every group separately?

```
    public static class TagMarker extends DoFn<TableRow, TableRow> {

    private Map<String, TupleTag<TableRow>> tagMap;

    public TagMarker(Map<String, TupleTag<TableRow>> tagMap) {
        this.tagMap = tagMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        TableRow item = c.element();
        c.sideOutput(tagMap.get(getTagName(item)), item);
    }

    private String getTagName(TableRow row) {
        // There will be your logic of determinate table by row
        return "table" + ((String)row.get("msg")).substring(0, 1);
    }

}


private static class GbqWriter extends PTransform<PCollection<TableRow>, PDone> {

    @Override
    public PDone apply(PCollection<TableRow> input) {

        TupleTag<TableRow> mainTag = new TupleTag<TableRow>();
        TupleTag<TableRow> tag2 = new TupleTag<TableRow>();
        TupleTag<TableRow> tag3 = new TupleTag<TableRow>();

        Map<String, TupleTag<TableRow>> tagMap = new HashMap<String, TupleTag<TableRow>>();
        tagMap.put("table1", mainTag);
        tagMap.put("table2", tag2);
        tagMap.put("table3", tag3);

        List<TupleTag<?>> tags = new ArrayList<TupleTag<?>>();
        tags.add(tag2);
        tags.add(tag3);

        PCollectionTuple result = input.apply(
            ParDo.withOutputTags(mainTag, TupleTagList.of(tags)).of(new TagMarker(tagMap))
        );

        PDone done = null;
        for (String tableId : tagMap.keySet()) {
            done = writeToGbq(tableId, result.get(tagMap.get(tableId)).setCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of()));
        }

        return done;
    }


    private PDone writeToGbq(String tableId, PCollection<TableRow> rows) {

        PDone done = rows
                .apply(BigQueryIO.Write.named("WriteToGbq")
                .to("<project>:<dataset>." + tableId)
                .withSchema(getSchema())
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
        );

        return done;
    }

}
```

I am not sure about rewriting variable *done*. Is it correct? Can it brake rewriting to GBQ after fail.

And this way is suitable only if you know list of tables which we want write to before parsing rows.

Comment: Sure -- data can be arbitrarily partitioned and those partitions can be written to different tables. However, the names of those tables still cannot be data-dependent. They are still determined at pipeline construction time, before any data is read.